# Элемент выходит за пределы grid-контейнера

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Блок `.today-news__best-news-content` выходит за пределы grid-контейнера. Как это исправить?

```css
.today-news__best-news {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  height: 350px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45% auto;
}

.today-news__best-news-picture {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.today-news__best-news-picture img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.today-news__best-news-content h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.today-news__best-news-content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="today-news">
  <div class="today-news__best-news">
    <div class="today-news__best-news-picture">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/870/536/354?grayscale&blur=2" alt="best news picture">
    </div>
    <div class="today-news__best-news-content">
      <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt neque corporis quaerat. Sed a eligendi ea quae molestiae alias dolorum nisi, est repellat, deserunt obcaecati consequuntur omnis temporibus nesciunt eos Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique pariatur consequuntur eaque quasi, aliquam inventore officiis totam cumque voluptatibus accusantium fuga magnam odit quaerat iure nihil necessitatibus quo! Id, neque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Magni possimus veritatis laudantium omnis ab in odit, maxime itaque iusto doloremque mollitia, eveniet modi, voluptatibus sint. Esse voluptates fugiat non fugit!adada sadad sada;kduiaodhoawdhoiadadawbdkjabhkdulgalwdyfakluydfaludyfaluydfaudytafdly</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо не писать слова без пробела.
А если и писать, то использовать перенос слова по буквам [`word-wrap: break-word`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap)

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.today-news__best-news {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.today-news__best-news-content h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.today-news__best-news-content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="today-news">
  <div class="today-news__best-news">
    <div class="today-news__best-news-picture">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/870/536/354">
    </div>
    <div class="today-news__best-news-content">
      <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt neque corporis quaerat. Sed a eligendi ea quae molestiae alias dolorum nisi, est repellat, deserunt obcaecati consequuntur omnis temporibus nesciunt eos Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```